# How do I eat a Hegui Fruit?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

The item info for a Hegui Fruit indicates that eating one restores 10 HP and 10 hunger. The description says that it can be eaten raw, but when I equip a Hegui Fruit it shows up as a throwable "attack" item rather than a consumable food item.

How do I eat a raw Hegui Fruit?

[image: Description for Hegui Fruit]

Comment: Could it be just a misleading description? I can't find any clue about it being edible, it's listed as a crafting item in the wikia.

Comment: @pinckerman The bottom of the infobox indicates the item restores 10 health and 10 hunger when consumed.